# Where can I download Java Mission Control(7) (OpenJDK11 or higher)?

Tags: java, jmc, jfr

Java Mission Control(JMC) was announced to be handed over from Oracle to the open source community from JDK 11 onwards.
However JMC is not bundled with the [OpenJDK11 releases](https://jdk.java.net/11/).

I read that JMC will be provided as separate [download here](https://jdk.java.net/jmc/), but there are no builds to download.
Also Oracle no longer provides a download on [their page about JMC](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html). 
And I can no longer find it in the [Oracle JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

The source is mirrored on [GitHub](https://github.com/JDKMissionControl/jmc) but there are also no build releases to download.

Where can I download the most recent open source licensed version of Java Mission Control?

Comment: [Seems there are no builds of JMC 7 as of now](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jmc/7/). JMC 6 is probably bundled with JDK 8 of Oracle

Comment: But that version is not licensed open source.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

JMC 7 has been released by Oracle - http://jdk.java.net/jmc

There are also other distributions:

- AdoptOpenJDK - https://adoptopenjdk.net/jmc.html ( or https://ci.adoptopenjdk.net/view/JMC/job/jmc-latest/)
- Zulu Mission Control - https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-mission-control/
- Liberica Mission Control - https://bell-sw.com/pages/lmc/
- Install the jmc module in Fedora - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/JMC_on_Fedora
- Build yourself - https://github.com/JDKMissionControl/jmc (official source for JMC 7 is at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jmc/jmc7/)
- Builds provided by Alexey Shipilev - https://builds.shipilev.net/jmc/

If you don't care about JMC working with the latest version of Java Flight Recorder, you can also use a JMC version included in JDK8, 9 or 10.

If you want to use the extra plugins for JMC, you need to use the Oracle release or the AdoptOpenJDK builds, or build yourself.

Comment: What is an updatesite and do I need it? I don't use Eclipse.

Comment: An updatesite contains extra features for JMC (or for any Eclipse application). These features include some extra functionality for visualizing JFX events in the JFR UI, an jconsole plugin for the JMX Console, and some others, see https://github.com/openjdk/jmc/blob/master/application/org.openjdk.jmc.updatesite.rcp/feature.xml

Comment: **JMC 7** was released recently and is available [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/downloads/jmc7-downloads-5868868.html) from Oracle and [here](https://jdk.java.net/jmc/) from open JDK