# Issues running Java Mission Control from CLI on Windows 10 because of JNI library errors?

Tags: java

I am trying to run Java Mission Control on my windows 10 machine and have so far not been able to get it to work. I have tried some of the distributions from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628015/where-can-i-download-java-mission-control7-openjdk11-or-higher). I tried the Zulu Mission Control, and AdoptOpenJDK, as well as building from source (had other issues with building from source). When Trying with Azul and AdoptOpenJDK I downloaded the zip files, unzipped them and tried to run the respective mission control programs. I ran them from the cmd prompt on windows 10.

From searching online the error I get seems related to Eclipse. Though I want to run this from the CLI and I don't have eclipse installed. Here is the error:

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library
"C:\IBM\InformationServer_113/jdk32\jre\bin\j9vm\jvm.dll"
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Here is what I get when I run "java -version" from cmd prompt.

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwi3270_27sr1-20140411_01(SR1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.7, JRE 1.7.0 Windows x86-32 20140410_195893 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_SR1_20140410_1931_B195893
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20140410_61421
GC   - R27_Java727_SR1_20140410_1931_B195893
J9CL - 20140410_195893)
JCL - 20140409_01 based on Oracle 7u55-b13
```

Comment: Use a hotspot based JVM. Not j9

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded to JDK8 and it works